# Django templates - how to run a method on a variable?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm new to Django, so maybe my attempts are pure heresy ;)

I'm trying to make a view which lists disponible conference rooms with its attributs, availability included.
I have 2 models: `Room` and `Reservation`. I'd like in the view to have a column saying if the room is available the day the page is displayed.

My `models.py`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    projector = models.BooleanField()


class Reservation(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('room', 'date',)
```

my `views.py`:

```
class ShowRoom(View):
    def get(self, request):
        rooms = Room.objects.all()
        time_now = timezone.now().date()
        context = {
            'rooms': rooms,
            'time_now': time_now
        }
        return render(request, 'rooms/list_rooms.html', context)
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'rooms/base.html' %}

{% block block_title %} Home {% endblock %}

{% block block_content %} 
{% if rooms %}

    <table  class="table">
        <thead>
            <td> Name </td>
            <td> Capacity </td>
            <td> Available </td>
            <td> Projector </td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    {% for room in rooms|dictsort:'capacity'  %}
        <tr>
            <td>  <a href="{% url 'rooms:detail_room' room_pk=room.pk %}">{{ room.name }}</a>  </td>
            <td> {{ room.capacity }} </td>
            <td>  Available? </td>
            <td> {{ room.projector|yesno:'yes,no' }} </td>
            
        </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
    <h1> You have no registered rooms yet. </h1>
{% endif  %}
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works fine, I need just to replace  this  `<td>  Available? </td>` line with a code, which would display "free" or "occupied" according to existing room reservations.

I've found out that maybe I should write a custom filter.

Here is my filter:

```
from django import template 
from rooms.models import Room, Reservation

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def check_reservation(queryset, now):
    return queryset.filter(date=now)
```

(I wanted first to make it working, and after make it display this "free" or "occupied".)

I've added to the template `{% load my_extras %}` and replaced the line I want to change with

```
<td>  {{ room.reservation_set.all|check_reservation:'time_now' }} </td>
```

The output is:

> ValidationError at /room/ ["'time_now' value has an invalid date
> format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Before adding the filter, I was trying this solution in the shell and it was working.

I don't know if there is something wrong with the filter, or I try to approach the issue from wrong side.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Check if time_now is getting passed as a string in the filter or a datetime object. That may be causing an issue.

Alternatively, you can add another field to your Room model as occupied = models.Booleen (default=False). Then in the views check if the date time and reservation match to change occupied to True. You can then pass that to context. Python is flexible than trying to do it in the template

Comment: result of  "print(time_now)": 2020-07-16
result of  "print(type(time_now)": <class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: but the same worked in the shell...

Comment: If your end goal is to display Available or Occupied, you can try adding a field to the "Room" model and change its bit to when the time / reservation clash. Then call that in the template:
{% if room.occupied %} Occupied {% else %} Available {% endif %}

Comment: @analytical_prat could you explain more this: "and change its bit to when the time / reservation clash"?

Comment: In the views you would check if time_now and date (from the reservation model) match. If they match then room.occupied = true else room.occupied = false. Passing these to the template tag will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another field to the the Room class:

```
occupied = model.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In the views you can check the date associated with the reservation and today's date.

```
if reservation.date == time_now:
  room.occupied = true
```

You can then filter with rooms that are available and which are not.

```
rooms_occupied = room.objects.filter(occupied=True)
rooms_available = room.object.filter(occupied=False)
```

In the template:

```
{% if rooms_occupied %}
  Available
{% endif %}
```